# In MVVM are DataTemplates considered Views as UserControls are Views?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, datatemplate

In MVVM, every View has a ViewModel. A View I understand to be a **Window, Page or UserControl** to which you can attach a ViewModel from which the view gets its data.

But a **DataTemplate** can also render a ViewModel's data.

So I understand a DataTemplate to be another "View", but there seem to be **differences**, e.g. Windows, Pages, and UserControls can define their own .dlls, one type is bound with DataContect the other through attaching a template so that Windows, Pages, UserControls can can be attached to ViewModels dynamically by a **ServiceLocator/Container**, etc.

**How else are DataTemplates different than Windows/Pages/UserControls when it comes to rendering a ViewModel's data on the UI? And are there other types of "Views" other than these four?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I use it, the DataTemplate is actually the way to link the View to the ViewModel. Typically my DataTemplates in MVVM look like that :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:FooViewModel}">
    <v:FooView />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: interesting, but then how does the rests of your XAML look? I tried a small example of this, compiled it and Visual Studio said it needed Administrator permissions (Vista), odd. Would like to see how you use this pattern in a project.

Comment: Basically, I put the "mapping" datatemplates in the App.xaml or the main window's XAML, and everything else is UserControls...

Comment: Are you using a ContentControl to pull in the ViewModel then, I'm trying this <ContentControl
 Content="{Binding CurrentPageViewModel}"/> with a data template like yours that does this "<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:PageModelsViewModel}"><v:PageModelsView /></DataTemplate> but it doesn't link them up, it just displays nothing.

Comment: @Thomas, this was really helpful, it helped me build my MVVM menu pattern I was after which however led to another issue here, perhaps you have solved this one as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026342/how-can-i-tell-my-datatemplate-to-bind-to-a-property-in-the-parent-viewmodel

Comment: Yes, I usually use a ContentControl to display the ViewModel. For the DataTemplate to be used, it must be accessible from the ContentControl XAML context.

Comment: After a lot of reading, a lot of suffering, and some insight, this is the most simple and powerful way to implement pure-WPF (no framework) ViewModel-First MVVM.

Answer (score 1):

What is making the most sense to me at this point in transitioning to MVVM is:

UserControls: Group views and controls together that are meant to execute an entire process for the user. I use a usercontrol for a slide-out drawer that I created that allows a user to flip through different classifications of parts (where each main part category routs the user through it's own selection process/wizard). Also look at Charting Controls.

Views: Basically a grid that groups related data and controls that populate desired data at the smallest level so it can be reused.

DataTemplates: Group facts about "items" like in a listbox or GridView. I think of this as just how the what text represents an object you're trying to gain information about in a list. So a control template would wrap the data template blocks to control the display behavior of that collection of data template-wrapped items.

That's how I understand it, but the boundaries are very fuzzy. I like the Apress book ***Pro Expression Blend 4*** by Andrew Troelson. He doesn't really give any data-heavy examples, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using a DataTemplate to bind the view to the viewmodel.
I am currently having performance issues using this approach as the view is refreshed everytime the view gets focus.
As you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770387/binding-tabcontrol-itemssource-to-an-observablecollection-of-viewmodels-causes-co) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2835430/value-of-text-box-disapears-binding-viewmodel-to-a-tab-content-control)

Unfortunatley I have not found a better option as of yet.