# Binding TabControl ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection of ViewModels causes content to refresh on focus

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol, observablecollection

I'm creating an WPF application using the MVVM framework, and I've adopted several features from Josh Smith's article on MVVM [here...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Most importantly, I'm binding a TabControl to an ObservableCollection of ViewModels.  This means that am using a tabbed MDI interface that displays a UserControl as the content of a TabItem.  The issue I'm seeing in my application is that when I have several tabs and I flip back and forth between tabs, the content is being refersh each time I change tabs.

If you download Josh Smith's source code, you'll see that his app has the same problem.  For example, click on the "View All Customers" button and scroll down to the bottom the ListView.  Next click on the "Create New Customer" button.  When you switch back to the All Customer view you'll notice that the ListView scrolls back to the top.  If you switch back to the New Customer tab and place your cursor in one of the TextBoxes, then switch to All Customers tab and back, you'll notice that the cursor is now gone.

I imagine that this is because I'm using an ObservableCollection, but I can't be sure.  Is there any way to prevent the tab's content from refreshing when it receives the focus?

**EDIT:**
I found my problem when I ran the profiler on my application.  I'm defining a DataTemplate for my ViewModels so it knows how to render the ViewModel when it is displayed in the tab... like so:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:CustomerViewModel}">
    <vw:CustomerView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So whenever I switch to a different tab, it has to re-create the ViewModel again.  I fixed it temporarily by changing my ObservableCollection of ViewModels to an ObservableCollection of UserControls.  However, I would really still like to use DataTemplates if possible.  Is there a way to make a DataTemplate work?

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of WPF is to unload items which are not visible, which includes unloading TabItems which are not visible. This means when you go back to the tab, the TabItem gets re-loaded, and anything not bound (such as a scroll position) will get reset.

There was a good site [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101007170247/http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx) which contains code to extend the TabControl and stop it from destroying it's TabItems when switching tabs, however it no longer seems to exist now.

Here's the code I use to prevent that issue. It initially was from that site, although I've made some changes to it. It preserves the `ContentPresenter` of TabItems when switching tabs, and uses it to redraw the TabItem when you go back to the page. It takes up a bit more memory, however I find it better on performance since the TabItem no longer has to re-create all the controls that were on it.

```cs
// Extended TabControl which saves the displayed item so you don't get the performance hit of 
// unloading and reloading the VisualTree when switching tabs

// Obtained from http://eric.burke.name/dotnetmania/2009/04/26/22.09.28
// and made a some modifications so it reuses a TabItem's ContentPresenter when doing drag/drop operations

[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_ItemsHolder", Type = typeof(Panel))]
public class TabControlEx : System.Windows.Controls.TabControl
{
    // Holds all items, but only marks the current tab's item as visible
    private Panel _itemsHolder = null;

    // Temporaily holds deleted item in case this was a drag/drop operation
    private object _deletedObject = null;

    public TabControlEx()
        : base()
    {
        // this is necessary so that we get the initial databound selected item
        this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// if containers are done, generate the selected item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            this.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            UpdateSelectedItem();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// get the ItemsHolder and generate any children
    /// </summary>
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        _itemsHolder = GetTemplateChild("PART_ItemsHolder") as Panel;
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// when the items change we remove any generated panel children and add any new ones as necessary
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnItemsChanged(e);

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                _itemsHolder.Children.Clear();

                if (base.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    base.SelectedItem = base.Items[0];
                    UpdateSelectedItem();
                }

                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:

                // Search for recently deleted items caused by a Drag/Drop operation
                if (e.NewItems != null && _deletedObject != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
                    {
                        if (_deletedObject == item)
                        {
                            // If the new item is the same as the recently deleted one (i.e. a drag/drop event)
                            // then cancel the deletion and reuse the ContentPresenter so it doesn't have to be 
                            // redrawn. We do need to link the presenter to the new item though (using the Tag)
                            ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                            if (cp != null)
                            {
                                int index = _itemsHolder.Children.IndexOf(cp);

                                (_itemsHolder.Children[index] as ContentPresenter).Tag =
                                    (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
                            }
                            _deletedObject = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (e.OldItems != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
                    {

                        _deletedObject = item;

                        // We want to run this at a slightly later priority in case this
                        // is a drag/drop operation so that we can reuse the template
                        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.DataBind,
                            new Action(delegate()
                        {
                            if (_deletedObject != null)
                            {
                                ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(_deletedObject);
                                if (cp != null)
                                {
                                    this._itemsHolder.Children.Remove(cp);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ));
                    }
                }

                UpdateSelectedItem();
                break;

            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                throw new NotImplementedException("Replace not implemented yet");
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// update the visible child in the ItemsHolder
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSelectionChanged(e);
        UpdateSelectedItem();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// generate a ContentPresenter for the selected item
    /// </summary>
    void UpdateSelectedItem()
    {
        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // generate a ContentPresenter if necessary
        TabItem item = GetSelectedTabItem();
        if (item != null)
        {
            CreateChildContentPresenter(item);
        }

        // show the right child
        foreach (ContentPresenter child in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            child.Visibility = ((child.Tag as TabItem).IsSelected) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// create the child ContentPresenter for the given item (could be data or a TabItem)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter CreateChildContentPresenter(object item)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        ContentPresenter cp = FindChildContentPresenter(item);

        if (cp != null)
        {
            return cp;
        }

        // the actual child to be added.  cp.Tag is a reference to the TabItem
        cp = new ContentPresenter();
        cp.Content = (item is TabItem) ? (item as TabItem).Content : item;
        cp.ContentTemplate = this.SelectedContentTemplate;
        cp.ContentTemplateSelector = this.SelectedContentTemplateSelector;
        cp.ContentStringFormat = this.SelectedContentStringFormat;
        cp.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        cp.Tag = (item is TabItem) ? item : (this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item));
        _itemsHolder.Children.Add(cp);
        return cp;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Find the CP for the given object.  data could be a TabItem or a piece of data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    ContentPresenter FindChildContentPresenter(object data)
    {
        if (data is TabItem)
        {
            data = (data as TabItem).Content;
        }

        if (data == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_itemsHolder == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        foreach (ContentPresenter cp in _itemsHolder.Children)
        {
            if (cp.Content == data)
            {
                return cp;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// copied from TabControl; wish it were protected in that class instead of private
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    protected TabItem GetSelectedTabItem()
    {
        object selectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (_deletedObject == selectedItem)
        { 

        }

        TabItem item = selectedItem as TabItem;
        if (item == null)
        {
            item = base.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(base.SelectedIndex) as TabItem;
        }
        return item;
    }
}
```

The TabControl template I usually use looks something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="TabControlEx_NoHeadersStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:TabControlEx}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type localControls:TabControlEx}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <!-- This is needed to draw TabControls with Bound items -->
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Height="0" Width="0" />
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_ItemsHolder" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with binding mode- did you try {Binding Mode=OneWay}?
Also binding to any of the 'DataSource' objects will cause the same issue.

Im not sure if oneway binding will be the desired behavior you are looking for but i would start there.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work.  I've updated my question... let me know if you can give any input.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the ObservableCollection. It’s because the View for the Customer is reused instead that WPF creates a new View for every Customer.

You might have a look at the Writer sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It implements the TabControl for a tabbed MDI interface as well but doesn’t suffer from the issue you mentioned in your post. The issue is solved in Writer by creating an own UserControl for every document ‘tab’.

Comment: Thanks @jbe, I know that I could solve the problem using an ObservableCollection of UserControls, but I'd prefer to use an ObservableCollection of ViewModels if possible.  I've updated my question... let me know if you can give any input.  Thanks.

Comment: When I started with the MVVM pattern I have used the DataTemplate mechanism of WPF as well for wiring the View with the ViewModel together. But I ran into a few issues like the one you mention here. That’s the reason why I wire them with MEF together. WPF just gets the Views (UserControls) and so I don’t need the DataTemplate for this scenario anymore.